# How do I get just the product additional information in the custom module

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Hi i am trying to create a page which will search a product and show the product 
there. Everything is working fine but i can't show the product additional information tab in the product.

**Here is my block code:**

```
 <?php

namespace Custom\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class Create extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_product;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $_category;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
    * @param Product $product
    * @param Category $category
    * @param array $data
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        Product $product,
        Category $category,
        array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_category = $category;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getWysiwygConfig()
    {
        $config = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig();
        $config = json_encode($config->getData());
    }

    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_product->load($id);
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->_category;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**Here is template code:**

```
<?php

$helper = $this->helper('Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data');

/** @var $this \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template */
/** @var $helper \Magento\Search\Helper\Data */
$helper_search = $this->helper('Magento\Search\Helper\Data');
 $product_id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('pid');
$product_coll = $block->getProduct($product_id);
$pname = $product_coll->getname();
$desc = $product_coll->getDescription();
$pSku = $product_coll->getsku(); 

$attributes = $product_coll->getAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
    echo $attribute->getAttributeCode(); echo '<br />';
    echo $attribute->getStoreLabel(); echo '<br />';
    echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel(); echo '<br />';    
    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); echo '<br />';
    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); echo '<br />';    
}
?>
```

Above code shows the product name, description and sku but it's now showing 
product additional data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searched lot over the internet i decided to show product additional information using the product attributes. Get all the attributes of product using `getAttributes()` method. Then filter the attribute using the group id for group **product details**. After that avoid the attributes which are not necessary like **sku, price, image etc.** Following is code may be it is helpful for some one.

**Block code:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Create extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_product;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $_category;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;
    protected $customerSession;
    public $_objectManager;
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
    * @param Product $product
    * @param Category $category
    * @param array $data
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        Product $product,
        Category $category,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_category = $category;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getWysiwygConfig()
    {
        $config = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig();
        $config = json_encode($config->getData());
    }

    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_product->load($id);
    }

     public function getSellerId()
     {      

         return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

     }

    public function getSellerProduct($mageProductId, $sellerId)
    {

        $sellerProductColls = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Vendor\Module\Model\Product'
            )
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                'mageproduct_id',
                $mageProductId
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'seller_id',
                $sellerId
            );

            $count = $sellerProductColls->getData();
            return $count;
    }

    public function getAttributeGroupId($attributeSetId)
    {
         $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config */
        $config= $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Config');

        return $attributeGroupId = $config->getAttributeGroupId($attributeSetId, 'Product Details');

    }


    public function getProductAttrValue($pid, $code)
    {
        $product = $this->_product->load($pid);
        return $product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    }



    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->_category;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**Phml Template:**

```
 <?php

   $product_id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('pid');
   $product_coll = $block->getProduct($product_id);
   $pname = $product_coll->getname();
   $pattr = $product_coll->getAttributeSetId();
   $extraAttr = array('swatch_image', 'old_id', 'name', 'url_path', 'required_options', 'has_options', 'image_label', 'swatch_image', 'small_image_label', 'thumbnail_label', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'sku', 'price', 'tax_class_id', 'image', 'quantity_and_stock_status', 'weight', 'updated_at', 'category_ids', 'description', 'status', 'price_type', 'sku_type', 'sw_featured', 'weight_type', 'shipment_type', 'links_purchased_separately', 'samples_title', 'links_title', 'links_exist', 'new', 'sale');

   $group_id = $block->getAttributeGroupId($pattr);
   $productAttributes = $product_coll->getAttributes();

   foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute):
     $code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

      if ($attribute->isInGroup($pattr, $group_id) && !in_array($code,  $extraAttr)):
         echo '<strong>'.$attribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel().': </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$block->getProductAttrValue($product_id,   $code).'<br>';

     endif;

  endforeach;

    ?>
```